# How to import anaconda python packages in C#

Tags: c#, python, anaconda, ironpython, python.net

I want to utilize sklearn and other ML packages in my C# application. Problem i am facing right now is that IronPython is python 2.7 and anaconda on my PC is python 3.6. Is it possible to somehow use existing anaconda package in C#?

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet